# What is the simplest way to convert array to vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What is the simplest way to convert array to vector?

```
void test(vector<int> _array)
{
  ...
}

int x[3]={1, 2, 3};
test(x); // Syntax error.
```

I want to convert x from int array to vector in simplest way.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use the `vector` constructor that takes two iterators, note that pointers are valid iterators, and use the implicit conversion from arrays to pointers:

```
int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v(x, x + sizeof x / sizeof x[0]);
test(v);
```

or

```
test(std::vector<int>(x, x + sizeof x / sizeof x[0]));
```

where `sizeof x / sizeof x[0]` is obviously `3` in this context; it's the generic way of getting the number of elements in an array. Note that `x + sizeof x / sizeof x[0]` points one element *beyond* the last element.

Comment: Can you explain it please? I already read that `vector<int> a(5,10);` mean `make room for 5 `int` and initialize them with 10. But how your x,x+... works? can you explain?

Comment: @UnKnown rather than selecting `vector<int>::vector(size_type, int)`, it selects `vector<int>::vector(int*, int*)`, which copies the range denoted by that pair of pointers. The first is overload (2), the second is overload (4) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: On c++11 std::extent is better than sizeof method. `sizeof x / sizeof x[0] == std::extent<decltype(x)>::value`

Answer (score 150):

Personally, I quite like the C++2011 approach because it neither requires you to use `sizeof()` nor to remember adjusting the array bounds if you ever change the array bounds (and you can define the relevant function in C++2003 if you want, too):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> v(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
```

Obviously, with C++2011 you might want to use initializer lists anyway:

```
std::vector<int> v({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

Comment: does it copy the array or it just points to it? i'm concerned with performance

Comment: `std::vector<T>` always owns the `T` objects. This has two implications: when inserting object into a vector they are copied and they are collocated in memory. For reasonably small objects, e.g. sequences of short strings, the collocation is a major performance gain. If your objects are big and expensive to copy, you might want to store [somehow resource managed] pointers to the objects. Which approach is more efficient depends on the objects but you have the choice.

Comment: so if i want to interface a c++ and a c libraries and copy from c-array to vector and back, there is no way of paying the penalty of 2 copies? (i'm using eigen library and gsl)

Answer (score 22):

Pointers can be used like any other iterators:

```
int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v(x, x + 3);
test(v)
```

Comment: In the real life you may want to abstract out the array size, for example using `const size_t X_SIZE = 3;` for denoting the array size, or calculating it from sizeof. I omitted that part for sake of readability.

Answer (score 14):

You're asking the wrong question here - instead of forcing everything into a vector ask how you can convert test to work with iterators instead of a specific container. You can provide an overload too in order to retain compatibility (and handle other containers at the same time for free):

```
void test(const std::vector<int>& in) {
  // Iterate over vector and do whatever
}
```

becomes:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void test(Iterator begin, const Iterator end) {
    // Iterate over range and do whatever
}

template <typename Container>
void test(const Container& in) {
    test(std::begin(in), std::end(in));
}
```

Which lets you do:

```
int x[3]={1, 2, 3};
test(x); // Now correct
```

([Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/L4EBIi))

Comment: "instead of forcing everything into a vector ask how you can convert test to work with iterators instead of a specific container." Why is this better?

Comment: @aquirdturtle because now, instead of only supporting vectors you support lists and arrays and boost containers and transform iterators and ranges and ....

Comment: and you didn't need to copy the data

Answer (score 11):

One simple way can be the use of `assign()` function that is pre-defined in `vector` class.

e.g.

```
array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

vector<int> v;
v.assign(array, array+5); // 5 is size of array.
```

Comment: Equivalent to the use of the ctor, which was mentioned in existing answers some seven years ago. Adds nothing...

Comment: worthy when the ctor is not callable, for example vector v already be constructed in other places

Comment: This is my preferred method, feels 'clean'.

Answer (score 2):

One way can be to use the array's bound in one go like this:

```
 int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> v(a, *(&a+1));
```

Comment: Wow, welcome to Stack overflow, tested and approved