# Iterate an std::vector by capacity

Tags: c++, stdvector

When I fill an `std::vector` knowing in advance the final size, I usually reserve its capacity in advance to avoid reallocation of its content (which on C++03 involves calling copy constructors for each object already stored in the `vector`).

This is a trivial example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.reserve(10);    

for( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0, capacity = v.capacity();
     i < capacity;
     ++i )
{
    v.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
```

There's a better way (less C-style) to loop around the `std::vector` capacity?

I'm looking for both C++03 and C++11 answers.

Edit: I rewrote the sample because all the answers and comments were going off topic, concerning only filling the std::vector with an array, which is not the point of the question.

Comment: A better as opposed to what? What is the problem with the current `fill` you want to avoid?

Comment: May be you just want to convert an array into a vector ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777603/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-array-to-vector

Comment: It would work with just `std::vector<T> v(t, t + size);`.

Comment: @SergeyA: better in the sense "more C++ style"... this is very much C style.

Comment: @mikedu95: this is just an example, I'm looking for a generic answer on how to loop around an std::vector capacity

Comment: @Lorenzo, what is 'loop around capacity'???

Comment: Please do not mix size and capacity. Notice: vector::size() <= vector::capacity() (capacity is a size threshold for reallocation)

Comment: @SergeyA: it means looping not for the size() but for the capacity(). For the size you have the iterators, for the capacity you don't.

Comment: I suppose `while (v.size() < v.capacity()) { ... }` is not what you are looking for. But I don't know what else could be the answer since using a reference to a as-yet-unconstructed element of the vector is UB even if space has been reserved.

Comment: @rici: I'm looking for something more object oriented... like iterators or range-based for()... these methods work with allocated items of the std::vector, but I have not been able to find something for reserved items.

Comment: ...Of course, you could assign through a `std::vector::back_insert_iterator` instead of using `std::vector::emplace_back`. I really don't see the advantage, though, and the back_insert_iterator cannot be compared with a std::vector::iterator, so it's not going to be much use for loop control. But, fwiw, it's an iterator :)

Comment: What *is* the point of the question? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Note that after your `std::vector::reserve(n)`, capacity may be greater than `n`, so you fill your vector for a size which is implementation specific...

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need a loop at all. There is an overload of `std::vector` constructor that takes two iterators. So just use `std::begin` and `std::next` to get the start and end of the passed-in array and make a vector from that.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> fill(const T* t, size_t size)
{
    return {std::begin(t), std::next(std::begin(t), size)};
}
```

Similarly you could use pointer arithmetic, which is what the above method essentially does under the hood:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> fill(const T* t, size_t size)
{
    return {t, t + size};
}
```

Comment: There is still a loop under the hood, and since the question starts with 'reserve', I have the feeling OP is talking about performance?... Not sure still.

Comment: @Sergey - If the vector constructor does any worse than using a reserve, you should ask for you money back from the library developer.

Comment: @BoPersson, would be hard given I got it for free :) But this is not what I meant. I was trying to say that my first impression was that OP is trying find a more performant solution, than reserve + loop. Possibly I am wrong. I am still not sure what they want.

Comment: @CoryKramer: thanks for the answer but it is off topic... I'm not looking at a way to fill a vector with an array (that was just an example, now I changed the code to better reflect my question), the question is about iterating the `capacity()` of an `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 or better, if you fill a vector knowing its size `std::initializer_list` will be your best bet.

You probably want to avoid initialising through a pointer to an array of const objects because that almost guarantees a copy. I appreciate that this is necessary in c++03, which should be one of your main motivations to move to a newer compiler if possible.

so:

```
std::vector<Thing> mythings { Thing(1), Thing(2), Thing(3) };
```

Is about as fast as you can get it. (not that there is no need for a fill function).

If you compile this on a reasonably modern compiler with optimisations on, you'll find that the `Thing`s will actually be created in-place within the vector. There is no faster way.